# Procedure Paging for GridView

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, webforms

I would like to in loop put data into @tbl2 table from @tbl table. Unfortunately I don`t know what I have to put into insert (INSERT INTO @tbl2 Values(@ID,?,?)) I mean second and third parameter.

**MSSQL 2008 R2**

For example(table @tbl):

SpecId | SP

3 | '5/1/2008 8:30:52 AM'

8 | '5/1/2008 8:30:52 AM'

9 | '5/1/2008 8:30:52 AM'

and If @count = 3 I would like to take this data (9 | '5/1/2008 8:30:52 AM')

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    SpecId BIGINT,
    SP DATETIME
) 
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE
(
    ID int,
    SpecId BIGINT,
    SP DATETIME
) 
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @firstNumber INT
DECLARE @secondNumber INT
SET @firstNumber = @PageSize * 10
SET @secondNumber = @firstNumber - 10 

WHILE (@count <= @TotalRowsNumber)

BEGIN

   IF @count > @secondNumber and @count <= @firstNumber
   BEGIN
        SET @ID +=1
        INSERT INTO @tbl2 Values(@ID,?,?)
   END


   SET @count = (@count + 1)

END
```

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to do? What output data do you want? With what input?

Comment: I would lie to put data from tbl to tbl2 INSERT INTO tbl2 Values(ID,SpecId,SP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there... look at this one:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
  Id int identity(1, 1),
    SpecId BIGINT,
    SP DATETIME
) 
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE
(
    ID int,
    SpecId BIGINT,
    SP DATETIME
) 
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @firstNumber INT
DECLARE @secondNumber INT
declare @PageSize int
declare @TotalRowsNumber int

SET @firstNumber = @PageSize * 10
SET @secondNumber = @firstNumber - 10 

-- Populate tbl
insert
into    @tbl
select  value1, value2
from    original_table

set @TotalRowsNumber = @@rowcount
set @count = 1

WHILE (@count <= @TotalRowsNumber)

BEGIN

  select  @value1 = value1
        , @value2 = value2
  from    @tbl
  where   Id = @count 

   IF @count > @secondNumber and @count <= @firstNumber
   BEGIN
        SET @ID +=1
        INSERT INTO @tbl2 Values(@ID,@value1,@value2)
   END


   SET @count = (@count + 1)

END
```

What i did. The @tbl needs to get an extra column, called Id. This is an identity column to use for referencing in a later stadium. Next you populate the @tbl with the original values. In the while loop you get the @tbl values into some variables (thanks to the @count = id you are looping through the records), and you insert them into @tbl2

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

I added to this table **ID int** and later in loop I create simple select for this two parameter:

DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    SpecId BIGINT,
    SP DATETIME
)